# dash.js not playing mpd file generated by MP4Box

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have transcoded and stripped the audio of an mp4 file as follows:

$ ffmpeg -codec:a libvo_aacenc -ar 44100 -ac 1 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 13 -b:v 2000k dir/out.mp4 -i dir/original.mp4

$ ffmpeg -i dir/out.mp4 -an dir/out_an.mp4

I've used the following MP4Box command to generate a mpd:

$ MP4Box -dash 30000 -dash-profile on-demand -segment-name out-seg -out dir/out_dash dir/out.mp4

This results in the following mpd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.5.1-DEV-rev4065 -->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500000S"    type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H2M11.77S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
  <Title>dashtest/output_dash.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period id="" duration="PT0H2M11.77S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="640" maxHeight="360" maxFrameRate="30000/1001" par="16:9">
   <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video"  lang="und"/>
   <ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio"  lang="und"/>
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.02" width="640" height="360" frameRate="30000/1001" sar="1:1" audioSamplingRate="44100" startWithSAP="0" bandwidth="2097272">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
    <SegmentList timescale="1000" duration="30046">
     <Initialization sourceURL="out-seginit.mp4"/>
     <SegmentURL media="out-seg1.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="out-seg2.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="out-seg3.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="out-seg4.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="out-seg5.m4s"/>
    </SegmentList>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

Comment: The profile should be `-dash-profile onDemand`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, changing -dash-profile from on-demand to onDemand does not create the m4s files, is there another field that needs to be included?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parameter -frag 30000, to make the file is fragmented to 30 secs. So the whole command like this

```
$ MP4Box -dash 30000 -frag 30000 -dash-profile on-demand -segment-name out-seg -out dir/out_dash dir/out.mp4
```

I tried with this command, i can play the mpd file in bitdash player as well as MP4Client